# Populate Number of rows in section from CoreData when there are 2 sections

Tags: ios, arrays, core-data, swift3

In my CoreData, I have a Person entity, and each Person can have multiple (to Many) Statement entities. The statement entity has an attribute called `amountOwed` which is a decimal amount. Right now my idea is to loop over all the amounts and add them up, if they of a positive amount add them to the positive array and if they are negative amount add them to that array. Then use that array to figure out how many cells each sections needs to display.

I created a `fetchedResultsController` and I am trying to use that for the for loop

```
for i in 0..<fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects!.count {

        let person = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?[i]

        let amountTotal = person?.value(forKeyPath: "statement.@sum.amountOwed") as? Decimal

        if(amountTotal! <= Decimal(0) )
        {
            postiveCellNumber += 1
            print("\(postiveCellNumber) postive number count")
        }
        else{
            negativeCellNumber += 1
            print("\(negativeCellNumber) negative number count")
        }

    }
```

Then, I'm trying to use those arrays in the `numberOfRowsInSection` function like so:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    switch(section) {
    case 0:
        return postiveCellNumber
    case 1:
        return negativeCellNumber

    default :return 0
    }
}
```

I don't think my for loop is looping properly as I get an error that says

> no object at index 2 in section at index 0.

Comment: You should edit your question to show your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.  Also, `postiveArray` and `negativeArray` are confusing variable names (I typed up an answer with a wrong assumption because of that).  You should change the names to something more meaningful, like `positiveEntryCount` or `numberOfPositiveEntries`.  Even better would be to simply populate the positive and negative results from Core Data into actual arrays.

Comment: Michael, the idea of using just numbers for the number of cells and not arrays is that I wanted the FetchedResultsController to still handled all of the ViewTable NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate actions. I updated the question so that it reads better

Comment: I gave you the exact solution of getting the value in your last post, but still you try to use unsafe methods of getting the values ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using two different queries, one for the positive values and one for the negative ones, with two different fetched results controllers? Then you can let the FRC do the iterating and counting for you.

You won't be able to use the FRCs to manage sections. You'll have to do that yourself. Specify `nil` for the `sectionNameKeyPath`. Then you want something like

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        return positiveResultsController.fetchedObjects?.count ?? 0
    }
    else {
        return negativeResultsController.fetchedObjects?.count ?? 0
    }
}
```

or maybe

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        let sectionInfo = positiveResultsController.sections![section]
        return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
    }
    else {
        let sectionInfo = negativeResultsController.sections![section]
        return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
    }
}
```

with similar logic for `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`.

Comment: Are you able to use multiple FRCs to populate one tableView? I've been told this might not be possible.

Comment: Yes. You'll just have to be pay attention to which section you're in, and use the right FRC to talk to. Make sure you have different cache names.

Comment: I ran into this issue while trying this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292064/why-is-indexpath-for-section-1-of-a-tableview-starting-with-a-value-of-1-0

Comment: @Dmorgan is right, you need to manage the section indexPath yourself. Whenever you're asked for section 1, you need to convert that indexPath to from [1, n] to [0, n] and use the "other" FRC.

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to identify the specific cause of the error, without seeing more of how your FRC and tableView are constructed.  But this bit looks suspicious:

```
    if(amountTotal! <= Decimal(0) )
    {
        postiveCellNumber += 1
        print("\(postiveCellNumber) postive number count")
    }
```

Surely the if condition is back to front: you should increment the positiveCellNumber if `amountTotal! >= Decimal(0)`?

But that aside, even if you successfully calculate the counts, you will then face the issue of working out which of the FRC's fetchedObjects should appear in each row of each section:

- You could do this "on the fly" in `cellForRowAt`, but that will involve iterating through the fetchedObjects again, to determine which appear in which section, which is clumsy and inefficient.
- You could separate the fetchedObjects out into two separate arrays as a one-off step, once the FRC has done its performFetch.  But you then need pretty ugly FRC delegate methods to update the two arrays whenever the FRC's fetchedObjects array is updated.
- You could configure your FRC to automatically assign its fetched objects to the correct section, by specifying a `sectionNameKeyPath` and associated sort descriptors for the underlying fetch.  The problem here is that it is not possible to sort the fetch using a calculated figure.  If you want to pursue this route, you will need to add a `totalAmountOwed` attribute to your `Person` entity, and to ensure it is updated whenever the related `Statements` change.
- Alternatively, you could follow @HalMueller's suggestion, and use two separate FRCs.  You would use complementary predicates for the underlying fetches, one to get only those `Persons` with positive amount owed, the other to get those with negative amount owed.  You can then use the fetchedObjects array for one FRC to populate section 0, and the other FRC to populate section 1.  Overall, I think this is the solution I would recommend.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to attempt Hal's idea.

Comment: are you able to populate one tableView with 2 different FRCs?

Comment: @icekomo Yes, this is perfectly possible.  Between Hal's answer above and your other recent questions/answers, you are very nearly there.

Comment: @ pbasdf, thanks I think I got this part working, but seem to have gotten stuck on this area now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41296550/tableview-doesnt-updatereloaddata-after-coredata-change-using-frc-swift-3                                 This is my first time using FRC so I'm a tad green to how it's working.