# Why is indexPath for section 1 of a tableview starting with a value of [1,0]

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3, tableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a tableView and it's split into 2 sections.

```
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}
```

Each section has it's own FetchResultController (FRC). This is my CellForRoatAt function

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "personCell", for: indexPath) as! PersonTableViewCell
    switch(indexPath.section) {
    case 0:
        print("this is section 0")
        let person = positiveFetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
        cell.personName.text = person.name
        //print("\(person.name!) is the name")
        //print("\(person.statement!.count) postive person statement count")

        if(person.statement!.count == 0){
            print("default")
            cell.statementAmount.text = "$0.00"
        }
        else{
            print("\(person.name!) has \(person.statement!.count) statement count")
            let amountTotal = person.value(forKeyPath: "statement.@sum.amountOwed") as? Decimal
            print("\(amountTotal!) this is the total")
            cell.statementAmount.text = String(describing: amountTotal!)

        }

    case 1:

        print("this is section 1")
        print("\(negativeFetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)) objects fetched")
        let person = negativeFetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
        cell.personName.text = person.name

        print("\(person.name!) is the name")
        print("\(person.statement!.count) negative person statement count")

        if(person.statement!.count == 0){
            cell.statementAmount.text = "$0.00"
        }
        else{
            print("\(person.name!) has \(person.statement!.count) statement count")
            let amountTotal = person.value(forKeyPath: "statement.@sum.amountOwed") as? Decimal
            print("\(amountTotal!) this is the total")
            cell.statementAmount.text = String(describing: amountTotal!)
        }
 default: cell.personName.text = "hello"
        }
```

This first section 0 works, like it should and I get the correct data back from the print calls. But section 1 throws me this error and crashes my app.

```
error: NSFetchedResultsController: no section at index 1 in sections list
```

CoreData: error: NSFetchedResultsController: no section at index 1 in sections list

When I print out the indexPath I get [0,0] for section 1 and [1,0] for section 1. I would think since I'm using 2 different FRCs for each section that the indexPath would start at [0,0] for each. Obviously I am wrong, but I don't know what to do to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

A FetchedResultsController is meant to be used by itself with a tableview, not with multiple FRCs to one tableview. So as soon as you try to use the FRC in section 1 it flips out - it only has one section that should be index 0 not index 1.

There's two ways around this:

**1. Fake the indexPath for section 1**

This approach is a bit buggy, I don't recommend it. But for section 1 you can manipulate the `indexPath` to be `indexPath.row, 0` instead of `indexPath.row, indexPath.section` (which right now is row, 1) to make it act like the FRC is in it's own table view by itself.

**2: use `sectionNameKeyPath` parameter of the FRC initializer to set different sections**

This property is used to differentiate sections of your FRC to help support multiple sections. The best example would be if you had a name field you could use `sectionNameKeyPath` of `name` to have sections in your tableview by name (like the address book is set up).

It looks like you are trying to do some neg/pos thing here with your multiple FRCs, if so perhaps a `BOOL` that lets you know if it's negative or positive so they can be differentiated into either section. This might not look like the best approach since you're adding a new property to your core data model that isn't necessary other than to differentiate sections, but sometimes in core data it's required to get the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: @ Drmorgan, right now I have a predicate on each fetch set up that does a calculation to determine if the sum is positive or negative. Would I be able to do something similar with the sectionNameKeyPath property. I would think this would mean I would only need one fetch request.

Comment: This question was about a solution to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41273826/populate-number-of-rows-in-section-from-coredata-when-there-are-2-sections. I don't agree that approach 1 is buggy; it's perfectly sound if you just do it. I'm not aware of any keypath you could set for the `sectionNameKeyPath` that would work  without some support in the NSMO subclasses. You'd have to guarantee that the section number gets updated every time the `statementAmount` changes, and make it a permanent entity property (since it's used by an FRC's predicate).

Comment: How could I set this line to use the [0,0] value that I need                            let person = negativeFetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)

Comment: @icekomo Don't use `.object(at: indexPath)`, use `.fetchedObjects[indexPath.row]` instead.

Comment: Do I need to use it like this? ` let person = negativeFetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects![indexPath.row, 0]`

Comment: @Hal Mueller, I had this question about reloading the data in the tableview, it seems that tableview.reloadData() isn't being called and I was wondering if the FRC had something to do with that. Here is the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41296550/tableview-doesnt-updatereload-after-coredata-change-using-frc-swift-3?noredirect=1#comment69795987_41296550